# search multiple strings in multiple files via command-line

Tags: search, csv, command-line

I have a txt file that contains about 500 values, one per line.  I need to check to see of any of those 500 values appear in any of 6 csv files each containing 100k lines.  I can search for one value in those 6 csv files using

```
 for /f "delims==" %%f in ('dir /s /b "P:\*.txt"') do FIND /N "[SEARCHSTRING]" "%~1%%f" >> "C:\found.txt"
```

but how do I do multiple searches automatically via command-line or batch file (CaSe SenSiTIve)?

Comment: Have you looked into batch scripts? You will probably have better luck there.

Comment: install a unix work-alike system. `fgrep -lf srchFile file1 file* ..` will list all files that contain at least one word in srchFile. If you take out the `l` and just leave `-f`, then the search will print the filename and the complete line that matches the word in your listFile. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=c:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=C:\destdir"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /s /b "%sourcedir%\*.csv"') do (
  FINDSTR /N /g:"yourtextfilecontaining500linestomatch.txt" "%%~fa") > "%destdir%\%%~nafound.txt"
GOTO :EOF
```

What you are asking is rather unclear. I used `c:\sourcedir` as the location of the `.csv` files and `c:\destdir` as the location for the reports. Replacing 
      `FINDSTR /N /g:"yourtextfilecontaining500linestomatch.txt" "%%~fa") > "%destdir%\%%~nafound.txt` with your original (with the double <kbd>></kbd> would accumulate the lines into a single file - if that's what you want. As it stands, a new file will be created with name the same as your `.csv`+`found.txt`

Comment: This is great!  I would like to use the >> to append all results to one file, but is there any way to also print the name of the file it was found in, not just the line #?  The /M flag for FINDSTR won't allow both.

Comment: How about a line `echo(===== file %%~fa =====` just before the `findstr` line? That should give you an obvious separator. You could change the `~f` to `~dpnx` in this line to show (your selection of) `d`rive, `p`ath, `n`ame and e `x`tension. Don't want a part of the name? omit the letter.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is to use a batch script. You can loop through each of the files one by one. If you want to do them all at once you need to thread your program.

```
for /L %%A in (1,1,6) do (
     Your code goes here
)
```

That batch script will loop six times. I am not really sure how you specify the file but if you loop through each file it will work.

So put your current batch script where I said "Your code goes here"

```
for /f "delims==" %%f in ('dir /s /b "P:\*.txt"') do FIND /N "[SEARCHSTRING]" "%~1%%f" >> "C:\found.txt"
```

But you need to edit it to point to the file that you want to search. If your files are 1.txt, 2.txt 3.txt then all you need to do is set your file name to the current loop iteration number.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using variants of this shell function for years:

```
ematch () {
    for f in $(find . -type f | grep -v '~' | grep -v \.svn\/) ; do 
    egrep "$1" "$f" /dev/null 2> /dev/null
    done
}
```

-> ematch "(string1|string2|string3)"

Feel free to adapt to your needs and post your mods here.